# MySQL cannot evaluate string value

Tags: mysql

I'm running in lack of understanding why a field value (varchar) containing TEXT of a table cannot be evaluated in a stored procedure.

```
set @Language=(Select Language from tblcustomer where cid=123);
If @Language='english' then
    set @salutation='Ladies and gentlemen,';
else
    set @salutation='Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren!';
end if;
```

The result is always the second option.

If I test it the select shows NULL for @Language

```
SELECT   @Language, Language from tblcustomer where cid=123;
result=  NULL, english
```

Same when I

```
DECLARE xxLanguage varchar(20);
set xxLanguage=(Select Language from tblcustomer where cid=123);

 SELECT xxLanguage, Language from tblcustomer where cid=123;
       NULL, english
```

But doing this

```
set @Language=(SELECT IFNULL((SELECT 1 from tblcustomer where cid=123 and Language ='english'),0);
```

gives the correct value 1. But then I cannot continue with the correct if..end result again.

```
If @Language=1 then
        set @salutation='Ladies and gentlemen,';
    else
        set @salutation='Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren!';
    end if;
```

gives the second (incorrect) option ('Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren!').

Any idea what's going wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: is 123 multi-lingual? no? then I don't see a problem https://dbfiddle.uk/ajNuRJYR , don't agree? publish sample data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: The fiddle example shows exactly what I expect and whats the result. But then at the IF statement the result will not be evaluated. That's the case i'm struggling with. Should I DECLARE xxLanguage  the variable or just set it as @Language? Both methods fail!

Comment: Where is the `IF` clause placed? In direct query or in a procedure/function?

Comment: The IF clause is inside the sp. There are multiple IF..THEN , some of them nested. But there is no error inside, only the non evaluation is the problem (obviously).

Comment: I still don't see a problem https://dbfiddle.uk/34BAnWiC.. You may need to restate the problem including the actual sp code you have and sample data.

Comment: Do not use SET, use SELECT INTO: `Select Language INTO @Language from tblcustomer where cid=123`.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`set @salutation=If (@Language='english', 'Ladies and gentlemen,', 'Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren!');`
https://dbfiddle.uk/nY6vjYLP

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. A very stupid one!
cid value comes from a IN parameter and was NULL iso 123!!

Therefor @Language was NULL for all the time!!!

```
set @Language=(Select Language from tblcustomer where cid=123);
```

Sorry about that!